# Anchor tags and checked input

Tags: javascript, html, css

Below is a simplified version on what I am trying to achieve.

Basically, there is link, and when its clicked it will go to an anchor tag on a different page.  This part works :)

When the other page anchor is reached, I want the checked box to be ticked automatically.  Wondering how you would do this.

The Idea is, there is a menu and I want that list item to expand/checked when the anchor tag visits it.

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/geargio72/oa48xmf0/)

```
<a href="#sample">click here</a>
<a id="sample"></a>
<input type="checkbox" />
<label for="sample">Sample</label>
```

Comment: you can use cookies for this purpose

Answer (score 2):

Using JQuery:

```
<a id="sample" href="#">click here</a>
<input type="checkbox" />
<label for="sample">Sample</label>

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#sample').click(function(e){
        $(this).next().prop( "checked", true );
    });
</script>
```

It's work for me.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this, maybe:

```
function check() {
    if (/sample/.test(window.location.hash)) {
        document.querySelector('#the-checkbox').checked = true;
    }
}
```

(presuming you give the checkbox an `id` of `the-checkbox`...)

If the anchor is on the same page, like in the JSFiddle you linked to, you should probably listen for a [`hashchange`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/hashchange) event:

```
window.onhashchange = check;
```

And if it's on a separate page, you should just call `check()` when the DOM is loaded (or at some point below the `<input type=checkbox>`).

Comment: Hey  what is the line refering to.  (/sample/.test(window.location.hash)).  is sample the folder and test the html file?  what is i wanted to check if #one was there or #two was there as they could have different events

Comment: is this right...   function check() {
var hash = window.location.hash;
    if (hash == "sample") {
        document.querySelector('#sample').checked = true;
    }
}